# MVC Ajax form javascript not fired with InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I'm using mvc `Ajax.BeginForm` to load a partial view that have a kendo ComboBox in it.

While using `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith` at the form's AjaxOptions, everything works fine and the partial view is loaded with the kendo functionality.

However, when changing the InsertionMode to `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter`, the partial view is loaded but without the kendo functionality, and I get a simple textbox instead of the auto complete combo box.

I have checked both scenarios page source and I can see the kendo jquery script in both of them, but it seems to get fired only when using ReplaceWith.

The code I'm using:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddNewPlanDetail", "Plans", new AjaxOptions
{
   UpdateTargetId = "AdditionalPlanDetailsHolder",
   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,//<--only changed this
   HttpMethod = "Post",
   OnFailure = "handleAjaxError"
}))
{  ......  }
```

All other code (Action, partial view) stays the same.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

To simplify the problem I reconstructed a sample without the kendo scripts and only with simple javascript:

My View Index.chtml:

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/unobtrusive")
</head>
 <body>
      <div>
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetPartial", "AjaxTest", new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            UpdateTargetId = "updateTargetElement",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,//<--Change this
                            HttpMethod = "Post"
                        }))
    {
        <h1>
            Ajax Form Test
        </h1>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
    <div id="updateTargetElement">
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
public class AjaxTestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetPartial()
    {
        return PartialView("Partial1");
    }
}
```

My Partial View Partial1.chtml:

```
<b>This is from partial</b>
<script>
alert('Fired');
</script>
```

The alert script is fired but only when using `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith`

Comment: Because your appending a new element to the DOM, you would to attach the plugin to it. `$(your new element).kendoComboBox();` which you could do in the `OnComplete` property

Comment: Also, you haven't posted your views, but the Kendo scripts should be in the main view (not the partial) otherwise your including the script multiple times

Comment: @Stephen, That's what i thought too, but to my surprise it does work without `OnComplete'. I've Edited the question and added a simple sample.

Comment: Additional checks: `InsertionMode.Replace`: scripts fired. `InsertionMode.InsertBefore`: scripts NOT fired

Comment: Interesting (have to explore that a bit more). But if you add `OnComplete="myScript"` and `var myScript=function(){alert('Fired')}` then you get the alert every time irrespective of the `InsertionMode` value, so I think this is the place to wire up the plugin to the new elements which have been added to the DOM

Comment: I did manage to solve this by adding `OnComplete` function and initialize the kendo ComboBox. However, this is interesting behavior that allows me to use the kendo mvc helpers (`@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor`) without worrying to wire up plugins and events after ajax forms are loaded. Would be nice if I could understand this and utilized it for rapid development.